# WebKit seems to miscalculate window/body size when page built with absolute positioned elements, how to fix?

Tags: android, html, css, browser, webkit

**Summary:**

I've been developing a mobile web application for a client and everything was going smoothly until an Android update seemed to ruin everything. The webpage is now rendering as if the window/body (DOM elements) height is much less than the actual screen height. The reasoning for this thoery is that the page is built around absolute positioned elements, thus elements with `bottom: 0` should be positioned at the bottom of the page (unless parent is relative of course, which it isn't).

The issue seems to only occour when a device is using a specific version of WebKit (so far issue only been spotted on Android devices). More specifically between version 534.13 to 534.30 (see debugging section below)

**About the layout:**

The site is using absolutely positioned elements to attach header and footer content to the top and bottom parts of the screen. A jQuery(window).load() event is used to calculate `bottom` and `top` numbers in order to position the elements correctly in relation to each.

> I know the website is not perfect, no need to mention it (I was new to
>   mobile optimised websites and went along with his ideas without
>   questioning them).

See the current implementation on: http://v-tone.com/ (note: this issue is not for website visits or any personal gain. Also the page can change at any time)

**The problem:**

The problem can best be illustrated by showing you a *working* and *not working* example:

Working: http://www.kjetil-hartveit.com/_misc/vtone/working.jpg

Not working: http://www.kjetil-hartveit.com/_misc/vtone/notworking.jpg

As you can see the implementation works in Android 2.2 but not in the new 4.0.3.

**Debugging:**

I have been debugging using jsconsole.com (remote debugging) and console logging and whatnot but haven't discovered any significant differences in the dimensions and calculations between a working and a faulty rendered site.

I have also tested several different implementations using webkit and also other rendering engines to try to pin down the problem. The results indicate there might be something buggy between WebKit version **534.13** and **534.30**.

You can see all the testdata here: http://www.kjetil-hartveit.com/_misc/vtone/Render%20comparison.xlsx (note yet again that this link may cease to exist at any time)

**Solution?**

My client really wants the site launched as fast as possible and so do I. We're not sure if it's worth it waiting for a possible Android update.

- Does anyone know a quick fix to the problem?
- Can anyone confirm it's a WebKit issue?
- Other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with WebKit 534.30 on Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android OS.

I made an accordion menu using CSS3.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="accordion">
  <li>
   <button>Button Caption</button>
   <div>
    <p>Some Information</p>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <footer>Some information in footer</footer>
</div>
```

After tapping on button the li-element changes its height using pure JavaScript (= button height + div height).
The problem was that opened li-element overlaped the footer element content.

The solution I made was to add translate3d and scale(1) to every interactive element:

```
.wrapper {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.accordion > li {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
.accordion > li > button {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

Then accordion menu began to work fine even in webkit 534.30.

Comment: I think the issue was caused by a silly hack to hide the Android navigation bar. Kind of funny actually, all that work because of a small script